# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> Anyone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom for routing in my **React and Next Js application**. The list of dependencies looks like this:

**Currently, my package.json looks like this**

```
{
"name": "MUSIC",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
 "dev": "next dev",
 "build": "next build",
 "start": "next start"
},
"dependencies": {
 "next": "10.2.3",
 "react": "17.0.2",
 "react-dom": "17.0.2",
 "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
 "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
 "yarn": "^1.22.10"
}
}
```

***Keeps throwing this error.***

> Server Error
> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
invariant
file:///Users/mahijendra/Downloads/new%20mac%20backup/code/portfolio/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.cjs.js (13:11)
Object.children

My component file **music/components/Navbar.js**

```
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Router} from "next/router";

export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
  z-index: 10;
  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */
`;

export const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    color: #15cdfc;
  }
`;

export const Bars = styled(FaBars)`
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 75%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: -24px;
  /* Second Nav */
  /* margin-right: 24px; */
  /* Third Nav */
  /* width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap; */
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 24px;
  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100vw; */
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavBtnLink = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #256ce1;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Second Nav */
  margin-left: 24px;
  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #010606;
  }
`;

function Navbar(props) {
    return (
            <>
                <Nav>
                    <NavLink to='/'>
                        <img alt='logo' />
                    </NavLink>
                    <Bars />
                    <NavMenu>
                        <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
                            About
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/services' activeStyle>
                            Services
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/contact-us' activeStyle>
                            Contact Us
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
                            Sign Up
                        </NavLink>
                        {/* Second Nav */}
                        {/* <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink> */}
                    </NavMenu>
                    <NavBtn>
                        <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
                    </NavBtn>
                </Nav>
            </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

**My index.js file music/pages/index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm breaking my head over this

Comment: I'd recommend you have a read through [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no switch and you have no routes from looking at what you have posted.

In your app.js you need to specify quite a few things to get the react router to work.

in the import section you are going to import the components like so.

```
import About from "./about" // or wherever its located
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then set up your router after the return.

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/> // you need one of these for each page you have 
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Alright thank you mate, I did what you asked me to do, Now it says "Error: Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM". Can we connect on discord or something? If that's not a problem

Comment: It is because you have things like `Nav` and `NavBtnLink` they are not a thing unless you have specified them so they need to go. Happy to help more just drop me a pm

Comment: I think it's because I added react-router-dom to next.js. Apparently next has it's own way of dealing things I suppose. your discord id please?

Comment: My discord is matt_roki#0888

Comment: I think as the next js is used, the react-router-dom should be removed?